# Monero withdrawal from gate.io on showing in wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, balance

Hi I'm very new to using monero and have a problem.  I purchased some monero from Gate.io in late December and my funds is still not in my GUI wallet. Gate.io transaction history show the transaction as complete with my public monero address as the txid. When I click the my monero address on there site in transaction history, I receive a message: Cant get tx hash due to parse error: 499X6M4t6Qd8UNjMfhyYmyPCcLxgQeHi6LRM9nNsP5mmSd7j599mQ9X5qjU1Bwm9XdASJftoAaX2WLstNztbst1YCQL4UK2.

Without a valid txid I'm unable to verify if the transaction was sent. I've contact them with tickets but haven't received help with the matter.  Just a statement 18 days ago saying:

your question is recorded. 
We will check it for you

it is not sent successfully, we may cancel it so that you may withdraw again

I tried the next steps dEBRUYNE's guide but still no monero. Has anyone else experience this? Is there a way to verify a transaction without txid? Any help is well appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try contacting gate.io for a transaction ID / hash? Without it we can't even verify whether the funds were correctly sent to your address.

Comment: Thankyou for your response.  I contacted them 18 days ago requesting the txid.  From my understanding the txid is the same as transaction ID / hash.  Is this correct?  After requesting the txid they responded once with the message above.  I contacted them several times since my original request and received no response.

Comment: You can't look up Monero addresses on the Monero blockchain. That's probably why you get a parse error. I really need the transaction ID / hash for further investigation. Alternatively, you could PM me (on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/dEBRUYNE_1/) your private view key and public address and I'll have a look on my side. The private view key is obtained by going to the `Settings` page and pressing `Show seed & keys`. Subsequently, take the private / secret view key. Lastly, an administrative note, could you stick to this "thread" and close the other one? It's cluttering the SE.

Comment: Hi dEBUYNE.  Thankyou again.  I deleted the other thread.  I will try to contact you on reddit.